# Solr change schema

Tags: solr, solr4

I am running Solr 4.1, and I need to change my schema. I modified the schema file, but it doesn't seem to pick up the changed schema. I even rebooted my server.

Also, how do I see my schem? I tried to do `curl http://localhost:1080/Mark/names/schema?wt=json` and I get

```
The origin server did not find a current representation 
for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

I can curl the same endpoint and get a document just fine.

How do I get Solr to pick up the new schema?

Comment: You can verify the same from the solr admin page...If you have a core created and the core is using any specific configSet...you need modify the schema.xml from that configSet...

Comment: Are you running Solr in cloud mode?

Comment: Check your solr log, especially during solr startup and post any error or warnings here. Are you sure, you have changed the right core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an error in my code that was indexing the data. I was setting the values for the new fields, but I did not realize that there was another method buried deep in the bowels :) that stripped it off.

Turns out, Solr picked up the changes, I just didn't send the data for it.